# Why do I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'YEETER'" when importing a module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I installed the module "[YEETER](https://github.com/shashankshirol/YEETER)" with:

```
pip install YEETER
```

When I try to import  this module (using `import YEETER`), I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'YEETER'
```

I am using Python 3.7.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did `pip install` work? Any errors?

Comment: yes it did thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install` will install packages for python 2. As you are using python 3, you have to install packages with `pip3 install`.

Or use python 2 to execute your code that is importing modules for python 2.

Comment: Thomas, can you delete your answer so I can delete the question?

Comment: @10yearoldPCAP Why would you do that? If my answer helped you, it might help others, too. This is not a personal help center. Both, questioner and answerer serve the community. Please (re-)read [this help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). It will give you an idea what all this effort is about.

Comment: @10yearoldPCAP Nobody is hating your question. It was just not a very [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question. I edited it for you to what I would expect from a good question: I changed the title to an actual question, I added all relevant info to your question (also all new info from the comments!) and I added a minimal code example that produced your error. I hope it helps. Learn from that and you will get more upvotes in the future, even from that question ;-)